# Django / DRF: Serializing QuerySet leads no "No attribute found error"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I serialize a multi-item queryset, it throws `id not found error` - despite each item having an `id` attribute (I checked this already).

Serializing: `json_data = SampleSerializer(Sample.objects.all(), many=True)`

Serializer:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sample_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ["sample_id",]

    def get_sample_id(self, obj):
        return encoded_id(obj.id)  # not found error
```

**Model**

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    objects = SampleManager()

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vector_column = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = (GinIndex(fields=["vector_column"]),)
```

**ViewSet**

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=["POST"])
    def search_samples(self, request):
        samples = Link.objects.all()
        json_samples = SampleSerializer(samples, many=True).data
        return Response(json_links, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 696, in get_context
    'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 511, in get_rendered_html_form
    return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 519, in render_form_for_serializer
    serializer.data,
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 248, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1882, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "/serializers.py", line 22, in get_sample_id
    return encoded_id(obj.id)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/samples/search_samples/
Exception Value: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Is the error being raised in the `encoded_id` function, can you add it? A traceback would be useful to add to the question

Comment: No, the issue is accessing the `.id` attribute of `obj` unfortunately. The encode function just spits back a hashed value.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?

Comment: Yup - check back in 1 min @IainShelvington

Comment: @IainShelvington included the traceback. I did a `print(f'{obj})` in the `get_sample_id` method and it went `{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { }`, so I believe it's caused by the empty dictionary appearing. (I have no idea why it's appearing though)

Comment: Odd that it's an OrderedDict, what is the type of `samples` before it's sent to the serializer

Comment: The search vector has weighting to it, which is throwing it off. The type looks like: `{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fde8065bb80>, 'id': 2, 'vector_column': "'2':2"}`

Comment: `SampleManager` is not returning a queryset. What is it doing and why does it not return a queryset?

Comment: There's no customization on `SampleManager` it's an just an empty manager i.e. `class SampleManager(models.Manager): pass`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you define the SampleAPIView class in your views directory?

```
class SampleAPIView(ListAPIView):
  permission_class = (IsAccessUser,)
  serializer_class = SampleSerializer
  queryset = Sample.object.all()
```

Also If you gonna get it as json format, I think you should use the

> json.loads()

Comment: I'm using a manual method on the viewset. Updating this now.

Comment: Added the viewset

Comment: Could you try the get_queryset(self) ?